# How can I get aliases and functions descriptions?

Tags: zsh, alias

I use oh-my-zsh and I have many aliases and functions I can't remember, so I use `alias ag="alias | grep"` to find out what an alias does. I also use [alias-tips](https://github.com/djui/alias-tips). But instead of getting the commands for just the aliases, I would like to have a way to **grep a description for both aliases and functions and also the commands for the aliases**. Although if it's possible to get the whole functions displayed too that would be better.

I've thought of using grep to get the previous line and if it's a comment I can display it. But I usually put the comments on the same line, unless the alias is too long. So I would have to check both the previous line and the same line for a comment to get the description.

I've also thought of putting all aliases and functions, and their descriptions in a file separated by some character and using that file to grep. But then I would have to repeat a lot of code.

Comment: Would standard `type` output format be suitable for you? Or `which` (builtin in `zsh` and like `type` some variation on `whence`)?

Comment: Any of those two format is fine, as long as they provide the command and description. `which ag` gives `ag: aliased to alias | grep`, `type ag` gives `ag is an alias for alias | grep`. What I had in mind was something like this `ag | 'alias | grep' | search for some alias` but the other ways look prettier.

Comment: Although if it includes the whole functions it would need to be something like a line with `alias_name: description` and below the alias commands or the whole function.

Comment: And where would it find that  `search for some alias` description?  You'd have to provide that somehow when you run `alias ag='alias | grep'`  to define that alias.

Comment: I would provide it in the form of a comment, either on the same line, or in the line above: `alias ag="alias | grep" # search for some alias`.

Comment: It would make it easier it you made it: `alias_description[ag]='search for some alias' with `alias_description` declared with` typeset -A`. Note that the alias value is already available in `$aliases[ag]`

Answer (score 0):

I use fzf as my function finder. You can probably extend this to include aliases as well?

see https://gist.github.com/tg0h/e301584f435023fae66c77675bdb6e4d for the fully commented code.

[image]

On the left, the fzf interactive finder lists all my functions and a short description of the function. On the right, the fzf preview window displays a preview of my function.

Unfortunately, I am in the middle of a refactor so my function finder is broken at the moment.

### Recipe

#### fzf

- Use fzf to fuzzy find your functions
  fzf's interactive finder displays all your functions, while fzf's preview window can be used to display your function in detail

#### bat

- Use bat to display your function with syntax highlighting

#### Function Definition

- Define your functions with a certain format and with a comment line describing what the function does. This will help you later when you use ripgrep to find your functions.

#### ripgrep

- Use ripgrep to do 2 things

1. For each function in your `<function folder>`,  provide its a. filename, b. function name, c. function comment. as a single line to fzf. This will be shown in fzf's interactive file finder (on the left of my screenshot)
2. For each function, find its filename and its starting and ending line numbers so you can provide it to bat. Bat can then be used to preview the function in the file. (shown on the right of my screenshot)

This will involve some regex wizadry but will be made simpler if you define your functions uniformly, see below for more details.

### Details

#### 1. Write your functions with a standard format

Write your functions in this format to make it easier for ripgrepping.

```bsh
# I do not omit the function keyword
function hello(){
# this function says hello (only the first comment line after the function will be used to be shown in fzf)
# this comment will not be shown in fzf's interactive finder (left of screenshot) later
echo hello world
}
```

#### 2. How to find all your functions (to feed to fzf later)

Assuming my functions follow the above format, I use ripgrep to parse all my files in my functions folder to extract the

- filename
- function name
- function description

using this:

```bsh
_fzf_home_getFunctions(){

  # -e '^\s*function\s+(?P<fname>[^\s(]+)'
  # [^\s(] - anything that is not a space or a (
  # the regex searches for function, whitespace, and then uses a named capturing
  # group of a word character
  # exclude commented functions

  rg \
    --follow \
    --type zsh \
    --color always \
    --field-context-separator '' \
    --no-context-separator \
    --only-matching -e '^\s*function\s+(?P<fname>([^\s(]+))' -r '$fname' -A 1 \
    --field-match-separator ' ' \
    $_fzf_homeFn_dir \
    | gsed -E 's!(\s*)(#)!\2!' \
    | gsed "s!$_fzf_homeFn_dir!!" \
    | gsed 'N;s/\n/ /' \
    | gawk '{$3="-"; print}' 
}
```

Note: I use gsed and gawk instead of sed and awk

#### 3. How to set up your fzf function previewer

```bsh
_fzf_home_displayFunction(){
  # given inputFile and inputFunc, use bat to display function body
  #
  # reads file and func
  # outputs file funcStartLineNumber funcEndLineNumber

  local inputFile=$1
  local inputFunc=$2

  local file=$_fzf_homeFn_dir$inputFile

  rg --only-matching \
     --multiline \
     -nH \
     -e '\s*function\s+'$inputFunc'\s*\(''(?s:.)*?(^\s*}$)' $file \
     | gsed '1b;$!d' | gsed 'N;s/\n/ /' \
     | rg '(?::)(\d+)(?::)' -or '$1' | join-lines | read -r funcStart funcEnd _

  bat --color=always $_fzf_homeFn_dir$inputFile -r $funcStart:$funcEnd
}
```

#### 4. Finally, feed fzf with your functions and set up the previewer

As a bonus, I also set up a keymap to edit the function directly from nvim. See my gist for the gory details.

```bsh
fzf-search-home-function-widget(){
  local result=$(
  _fzf_home_getFunctions | fzf --ansi \
    --preview="_fzf_home_displayFunction {1} {2}" \
    --bind "ctrl-e:execute(_fzf_home-function_nvim_edit {1} {2} < /dev/tty > /dev/tty 2>&1)"
)
zle reset-prompt;
LBUFFER+=$result
}
```